# DXL get full path of the source link

Tags: ibm-doors

I am iterating through all the objects in a module, and for every in link I want to print its full path (string path = source(link) - I tried this but only returns the name, I want the absolute path, not the relative one.) How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LinkRef lrIn
Object o = .... (e.g. for o in ...)

for lrIn in each (o <- "*") do {
  print (  //-
    "there is a link going from object " //-
    (sourceAbsNo (lrIn))  //-
    " of "  //-
    (fullName sourceVersion lrIn)  //-
    " to object " //-
    (o."Absolute Number""") //-
    ".\n" //-
  )
}
```

assuming that by "it" you mean the module containing the object containing the corresponding out link, not the link module.

Comment: There’s also an undocumented function ’rootName_’ that you can use in place of ’fullName’ to get a path to the database root instead of the nearest parent project. Be mindful that undocumented = unsupported = subject to unannounced change, though...